# Bootstrap width whitespace issue avilon theme

Tags: html, css

I having issues that you can drag website to left and it seems like width is larger than viewport.

When website load it seems to work but then i can click left on mouse and drag it....and then you see whitespace that appear.

No idea where this is happening. Im using https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/themes/Avilon/ theme.

See images below:

Problem image where you can see whitespace

[image]

How it suppose to look

[image]

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: The problem is that is think i need to post everything.... You can see for yourself at http://beta.northbricks.com

Remember to go into "App mode" to see this problem.